# Exception Handling for Inserts in PLSQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query related to the behaviour of PLSQL block having exception handler like below sample:

```
Begin 

1 liner Insert into (Select.. union all..);

Exception
When others 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ERRORM);
END 

END;
/
```

will this block commit the insert on successful run and rollback or do nothing on constraint error?

Basic idea is to make sure all the processing of lines/procedures/sqls etc before and after this PLSQL block are unaffected by the result of this block as I am unsure about commits with a savepoint in plsql and rollback in exception handler as a solution to it.

Comment: A PL/SQL block has an implicit save point at the start and will roll back to it on failure, so if you (1) do some DML without committing, then (2) execute a PL/SQL block, if the block fails it will roll back its own changes and leave you with (1). That's the default behaviour and it's usually what you want. It's a common beginner mistake to add `when others` logic that breaks it. I'd write this as an answer but maybe others have already covered it, if it's the kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, there is no implicit save point at the start of a PL/SQL block (`BEGIN`), though there is one at the start of a *call* from the client to execute PL/SQL. If you have nested `BEGIN..END` blocks within, when you don't trap an exception it raises out through the call stack until it is thrown to the client, which gives their single database call a failure condition, so Oracle rolls back the transaction to where it was when the client issued the call (not just from the start of the last `BEGIN`). `WHEN OTHERS` doesn't "break" it, it is intentionally preventing unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Paul, good point, I meant the whole call is savepointed, it isn't part of the `begin` keyword. The question seems to be about PL/SQL blocks in SQL\*Plus scripts, and it is often not appreciated that these have implicit savepoints and rollbacks that do exactly what we normally want, which is to treat multiple DML statements as a single unit that either succeeds in its entirety or else rolls back to its start leaving any earlier uncommitted changes intact. When developers think they need to implement this themselves they often add an exception handler that is less useful than they think.

Answer (score 2):

It won't commit; why would it? (unless your tool is set to *autocommit*, which is - probably - rarely a good decision).

Let's try it: sample table first:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(30));

Table created.
```

Insert initial value:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('Some text, before PL/SQL');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
------------------------------
Some text, before PL/SQL

SQL> set serveroutput on
```

PL/SQL block; read comments within it:

```
SQL> begin
  2    -- This is valid
  3    insert into test values ('Within PL/SQL');
  4
  5    -- This won't work and will raise an exception.
  6    -- I can't insert a 100-characters long string into a varchar2(30) column
  7    insert into test values (rpad('x', 100, 'x'));
  8  exception
  9    when others then
 10      dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
 11  end;
 12  /
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."TEST"."COL" (actual: 100,
maximum: 30)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OK; exception is being raised. What is the table contents?

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
------------------------------
Some text, before PL/SQL
Within PL/SQL

SQL>
```

As `exception` section just displays error message, it doesn't actually *handle* anything. See [Unhandled exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-494984A3-37E6-41BF-9BB9-05A693CD9577), which says:

> If a stored subprogram exits with an unhandled exception, PL/SQL does not roll back database changes made by the subprogram.

That's what happened here.

---

If you explicitly rolled back (see line #11):

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
------------------------------
Some text, before PL/SQL

SQL> begin
  2    -- This is valid
  3    insert into test values ('Within PL/SQL');
  4
  5    -- This won't work and will raise an exception.
  6    -- I can't insert a 100-characters long string into a varchar2(30) column
  7    insert into test values (rpad('x', 100, 'x'));
  8  exception
  9    when others then
 10      dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
 11      rollback;
 12  end;
 13  /
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."TEST"."COL" (actual: 100,
maximum: 30)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Table contents: it is empty now:

```
SQL> select * from test;

no rows selected
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the other DML operations in your transaction unaffected by a failure in one DML, you only need to trap it:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Assuming the single column in my imaginary "test" table has a PK on it, the second insert of values 2 will fail. But you should end up with 1,2 and 3 in the table. When a DML operation fails, it's work is rolled back but not the entire transaction. That only happens if a ROLLBACK is issued or the client disconnects leaving the transaction open.

If however you have multiple DMLs that you want to trap and a failure in either should undo all their work but not the work done earlier, then you will need a savepoint:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);

  SAVEPOINT optionalthings;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT optionalthings;
  END;

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (4);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

This should result in 1,2 and 4. The failure on inserting 2 the second time would undo the successful insert of 3 because of the rollback to savepoint, but without removing 1 and 2 which occurred before the savepoint.

Finally, if you want a failure to rollback *all* work done in the transaction (which is more common), then you simply need a plain `ROLLBACK`:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (4);
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

This will result in no rows at all in the table. the successful insert of 1,2 and 3 are rolled back when the second attempt to insert 3 raises an error. The insert of 4 (and the commit) will never have been reached, because the exception transferred control to the exception handler, skipping whatever remained in the `BEGIN..END` block. If you want 4 to still show up, then place it later:

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
  END;

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (4);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

This will result in just 4.

Comment: Useful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the whole anonymous block will behave as a single unit, either succeeding or failing in its entirety. The client sets a savepoint before the call and rolls back to it on failure.

```
SQL> create table demo (numcol integer);

Table created.
```

```
SQL> insert into demo (numcol) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into demo (numcol) values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into demo (numcol) values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> begin
  2     insert into demo (numcol) values (4);
  3     insert into demo (numcol) values (5);
  4     insert into demo (numcol) values ('banana');
  5  end;
  6  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL> select * from demo;

    NUMCOL
----------
         1
         2
         3

3 rows selected.
```

The three rows we inserted before the failed block are still there, and still uncommitted.

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select * from demo;

no rows selected
```

As for your question,

> *will this block commit the insert on successful run?*

No, there is no implicit commit. You as the developer would have to include a `commit` keyword (or something else that commits, such as a DDL statement) if that's what you want it to do.

Comment: On error, the plsql block fails therefore, no commits as "procedure completed successfully" is the message which we get on successful block execution. Hence, when you rollback it rollbacks to entire inserts. Try to pass a rollback in plsql block itself when others/error_criteria then rollback. Those 3 individual inserts as well are not committed by default

Comment: @Himanshu I didn't go into all the ways that beginner developers can mess up blocks like this (e.g. in deployment scripts) but yes that is a very common one.